# Fill svg path with canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, snap.svg

I am using SVG to make a custom shape using path:

e.g. `<path d="M 180,160 0,218 0,0 180,0 z" >`

I also use snap.svg to transform that path on hover to:

`m 180,34.57627 -180,0 L 0,0 180,0 z`

What I want to achieve is to fill that path with a canvas that I animate with javascript and make it inside the shape and also transform with the shape on hover.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: you could fill the path with an image and write canvas data into the image which you animate with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices depending on your exact needs. Here are some of these choices :

- **You could use a [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)** to append the canvas directly in your svg, then use a clipPath on it, but this will limit the support to IE>=11.

```html
<svg id="svg" width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <style>
      #clickHandler {
        pointer-events: all;
      }
    </style>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <path id="yourPath" d="M 180,160 0,218 0,0 180,0 z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <foreignObject id="fO" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#myClip)">
    <canvas xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
  </foreignObject>
  <script>
    var pathes = ["M 180,160 0,218 0,0 180,0 z", "m 180,34.57627 -180,0 L 0,0 180,0 z"]
    var current = 0;
    fO.onclick = function() {
      current = (current + 1) % 2;
      yourPath.setAttribute('d', pathes[current]);
    };
     // canvas noise
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageData = ctx.createImageData(300, 300);

    function animCanvas() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animCanvas);
      imageData.data.forEach(function(v, i, a) {
        a[i] = Math.random() * 255;
      });
      ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }
    animCanvas();
  </script>
</svg>
```

- **You could place your canvas behind the svg with CSS** and absolute positioning, you'd also have to append a background inside your svg, with your path set as mask, and a copy of your path to handle the mouse event. Here you'd gain all HTML5 browsers support, but you'll loose in svg z-index positioning.

```js
var pathes = ["M 180,160 0,218 0,0 180,0 z", "m 180,34.57627 -180,0 L 0,0 180,0 z"]
var current = 0;
clickHandler.onclick = function() {
  current = (current + 1) % 2;
  yourPath.setAttribute('d', pathes[current]);
};
// canvas noise
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageData = ctx.createImageData(300, 300);

function animCanvas() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animCanvas);
  imageData.data.forEach(function(v, i, a) {
    a[i] = Math.random() * 255;
  });
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
animCanvas();
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
<svg id="svg" width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <style>
      #clickHandler {
        pointer-events: all;
      }
    </style>
    <path id="yourPath" d="M 180,160 0,218 0,0 180,0 z" />
    <rect id="bg" x="-1%" y="-1%" width="102%" height="102%" />
    <mask id="myMask">
      <use xlink:href="#bg" fill="white" />
      <use xlink:href="#yourPath" fill="black" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#bg" mask="url(#myMask)" fill="white" />
  <use xlink:href="#yourPath" fill="none" id="clickHandler" />
</svg>
```

- **Or you could do everything on the canvas.**
  In below example, I use `Path2D` constructor, which wasn't supported in earlier implementations of the canvas API, but you can also achieve the same with different functions calls, or there even exist some Path2D polyfills.

```js
var pathes = [
  new Path2D("M 180,160 0,218 0,0 180,0 z"),
  new Path2D("m 180,34.57627 -180,0 L 0,0 180,0 z")
];
var current = 0;

canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
  var x = evt.clientX - this.offsetLeft,
    y = evt.clientY - this.offsetTop;

  if (ctx.isPointInPath(pathes[current], x, y)) {
    current = (current + 1) % 2;
  }
};

function clipCanvas() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  ctx.fill(pathes[current]);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'; // not really needed with putImageData
}
// canvas noise
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageData = ctx.createImageData(300, 300);

function animCanvas() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animCanvas);
  imageData.data.forEach(function(v, i, a) {
    a[i] = Math.random() * 255;
  });
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

  clipCanvas();

}

animCanvas();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```